# Reachability check when several view controllers are used

Tags: ios, reachability

I need to test for reachability, and the approaches mentioned in this question [How to check for an active Internet connection on iOS or OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk) seem appropriate.  But my App uses a Tab Bar controller, which in turn deploys multiple View Controllers.  Do I need to implement reachability testing in each View Controller, or can I just set it up once in the AppDelegate.m (and then set a CONNECTION_OK flag [for the View Controllers to test] as notification messages came in)?  Trying to keep things as simple as possible.  Examples welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I use the one from [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html).  In particularly these two class methods to check for Internet connectivity or local WiFi availability.  I do it right before there is a need to connect to Internet or local WiFi.

```
//  Should be used by applications that do not connect to a particular host
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityForInternetConnection;
 
//reachabilityForLocalWiFi- checks whether a local wifi connection is available.
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityForLocalWiFi;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are thinking of doing is spot-on. You can merely implement the reachability check within your AppDelegate and update a state variable (your CONNECTION_OK flag) that your view controllers can query. This is one of the proper ways to do it (from a programming style perspective).